# 30 days in Doctrine Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

i would like add clause where - max 30 days from now.

in database i have timestamp:

2011-08-30 20:29:35

```
id  | name | date
1   | aaa  | 2011-08-30 20:29:35
2   | vvv  | 2011-08-10 20:29:35
3   | bbb  | 2011-07-10 20:29:35
4   | fff  | 2011-08-14 20:29:35
5   | ddd  | 2011-06-10 20:29:35


$query = Doctrine_Core::getTable('News')->createQuery('a');
$query->addWhere('date ????????');
```

How can i get all news recent 30 days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$query->andWhere('date > ?', date('Y-m-d', time() - 60*60*24*30))

Answer (score -1):

MySQL provides another handy solution :

```
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

see : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: The question is about doctrine, not specifically MySQL. The question asker did not mention his/her db engine, so we should assume he wants to have a db engine independent answer.